# XML Element Case Sensitive Issue

Tags: xml, linq

I have xml as:

```
<FlOOR>
           <FloorID>1</FloorID>
           <Floor>1st Floor</Floor>
</FlOOR>
```

I am trying to use

```
var floorList = document.Root.Descendants("FLOOR").Elements("Floor").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

but not helpful. I want to get `<Floor>` value into list.

Comment: Can you show at least two items that you want into the list?

Comment: I wanted to get `<Floor>1st Floor</Floor>` inner value. Parent Node Name is also FLOOR.

Comment: You said you wanted a LIST which usually implies more than one results.

Comment: sorry for that, actually there are lots of <Floor> elements.

Comment: Resolved by correcting the `<FlOOR>` / `"FLOOR"` spelling issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (XElement element in document.Descendants("Floor"))
          {
            cmbBoxFloor.Items.Add(element.Value);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive. If you ignore the fact, your code won't work. I'm not sure why that is an issue.

Comment: Yes, its case sensitive, but  `document.Root.Descendants("FLOOR").Elements("Floor").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();` NOT worked, And`XElement element in document.Descendants("Floor")` worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the encoding.  When I typed the tag names I didn't get results.  When I copied and pasted the tag names into the code it worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var floorList = document.Descendants("FlOOR").Select(x => new
            {
                id = (int)x.Element("FloorID"),
                name = (string)x.Element("Floor")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```